# Create empty array without using List<object>

Tags: java, arraylist

If I want to create an "unlimited" array I know I can use a list (There is a lot of information on this and other forums)

But what if I don't want to make a list? Is there another way?
Because I want to use a float array in another function and it's kind of a hassle to use a list in this case.

This is what I wrote so far with the listing

```
List<Float> listfloat = new ArrayList();
listfloat.add((float)0.1); //example
listfloat.add((float)1.2);

float data[]= new float[listfloat.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < listfloat.size(); ++i)
{
    data[i] = listfloat.get(i);
}

return data ;
```

But I would prefer something like this

```
float data[]; //unknown size

for(i=0 ; i< sizeiwant; i++)
{
    data[i] = mydata;
}

return data ;
```

I know that it will work! I just want to optimise my coding =)

Thank you for reading =)

Comment: What do you mean by *Unlimited array*?. Do you mean a *dynamically sized array*?

Comment: You can always convert your list to an array using `list.toArray()`

Comment: And how does "unlimited" translate to "empty" as per your title? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: `Optimise = ArrayList`. It is dynamic, fast what not. `int []a = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];` is not at all optimal.

Comment: The real question here is how can a list be more of a hassle than an array, especially when you can change a list to an array. Java is awesome to get away from arrays which are slow, hard to iterate through, difficult to remove elements from, and (as you are having issues with) shouldn't even be dynamic. This isn't PHP :P

Comment: @blahfunk Java arrays are slow?

Comment: Java arrays are not slow or hard to iterate over.

Comment: Comparatively to lists and arraylists they are. Lists are far easier to work with and faster as the lists get bigger.

Comment: I'm really confused over here. Sorry for being unclear I'm new to java and Lists.

I need to use a float in another function that I can't change. I'm still fighting with List but it doesn't work. 

By "empty" I meant without telling it the size. In C I would use malloc()
Here I can't even use List! But that's probably because I'm a newbie, I know there's a way or else nobody would suggest it.

Comment: @Annaïck I think you need to include some code in your question to show what you're trying. You've now mentioned floats which don't appear in question, so this is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. You could convert a list to an Array using `list.ToArray()`
2. You could dynamically resize the array by changing the size of the array every time you add an element to the array. Here is how you would do that:

   ```
   //initialize array of size 10.
   int[] array=new int[10];
   //make copy of array
   int[] arrayCopy=array.clone();
   //expand array size by 1
   array=new int[array.length+1];
   //give value to new array index
   array[array.length-1]=0;
   //copy values from 'arrayCopy' to array
   for(int x=0;x<arrayCopy.length;x++){
   array[x]=arrayCopy[x];
   }
   ```

Hope this helped.

Comment: You can use Array.Resize(ref array, 6);

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided I would recommend to use an Array and create a method that is called when your array is full and returns a copy of the original array with more space in this way is you are kind of simulating dynamic size allocation.

Comment: I don't think that would be the best solution. Even though it would be easy to write it would take a long time to run if it Array is huge. And my Array will be huge. But that's not a bad idea!

Comment: Still... List seems the way to go. Especially considering that converting a List it back into an Array and vice versa is really simple

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are fixed-size, so your second piece of code is never going to work.

If you want a data type that can resize, you should use an `ArrayList`. On the other hand, there are times when using primitive array like a `float[]` is quicker and more convenient.

As a result, the need to convert between `List<Float>` and `float[]` in the way you do it in the first block of code is fairly common, and there is no way to do it in one line (unless you use an external library).

I advise writing a utility method to do the conversion

```
public static float[] listToArray(List<Float> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    float[] temp = new float[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = list.get(i);
    return temp;
}
```

(This method could be improved, as it has poor performance for a `LinkedList` where `get` is linear).

Annoyingly, you need 8 methods like this for the 8 primitive types, and 8 methods to do the conversions in the other direction. As things stand at the moment, there is no way to write generic code over primitive types, so code duplication like this is common.

Comment: I have code that works fine with List. I just wanted to know if you HAVE to use List. Apparently no but it's ease to use so why use something else?

Comment: @Annaïck If you have no idea in advance how many floats you need, the answer is that you have to use a List.

Comment: @Annaïck Also note that `list.toArray()` does not return a primitive array. It returns an `Object[]` (or a `T[]` if you use the other overload). `float[]` is quicker and more lightweight than an `Object[]` or an `ArrayList<Float>` because the values are not boxed.